# what is the difference between del a[:] and a = [] when I want to empty a list called a in python?

Tags: python

Please what is the most efficient way of emptying a list?

I have a list called `a = [1,2,3]`. To delete the content of the list I usually write `a = [ ]`. I came across a function in python called `del`. I want to know if there is a difference between `del a [:]` and what I use.

Comment: just as a clarification, `del` in python is actually a _statement_, not a _function_.

Comment: In Python 3, *please* use `a.clear()`. The docs state it's equivalent to `del a[:]` and *way* more legible.

Comment: And of course there's also `a[:] = []` which more or less does the same as `del a[:]`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is a difference, and it has to do with whether that list is referenced from multiple places/names.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> del a[:]
>>> print(b)
[]

>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> a = []
>>> print(b)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Using `del a[:]` clears the *existing* list, which means anywhere it's referenced will become an empty list.

Using `a = []` sets `a` to point to a *new* empty list, which means that other places the original list is referenced will remain non-empty.

The key to understanding here is to realize that when you assign something to a variable, it just makes that name point to a thing. Things can have multiple names, and changing what a name points to doesn't change the thing itself.

Comment: This example was clear and simple to understand

Comment: I'd also point out that `a = []` is faster than `del a[:]`

Comment: @JosiahDaniels, that technically only remains true if `a` is not the last reference to the list. If it is, then reassigning it will trigger garbage collection to essentially call `del a[:]` anyway behind the scenes.

Comment: @Amber @mintchkin Do you have any information on runtime? To me it seems that `del a[:]` has to iterate over every member of `a` (and then alter the list e.g. resize or something?) whereas `a = []` "just" creates a new list and abandones the old one (which then has to be gced; maybe at a "more appropriate time"? e.g. deleting lots of lists and only starting gc one time vs. starting gc each time (increased overhead)).

Comment: @syntonym: gc doesn't work like that in CPython. It reference-counts first, and only defers to a more appropriate time when there are reference loops that simple refcounting doesn't handle. So `a = []`, where `a` is the only reference to its referand, does normally result in immediate disposal of the list that has been abandoned. Freeing the list does what you say, iterate over the contents dereffing (and possibly freeing) each element. But if you used a Python implementation with Java-style gc, then I think `del a[:]` wouldn't have to do the work immediately. Unless I've missed something.

Answer (score 11):

This can probably best be shown:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(a)
45556280
>>> del a[:]
>>> id(a)
45556280
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> id(b)
45556680
>>> b = []
>>> id(b)
45556320
```

When you do `a[:]` you are referring to all elements within the list "assigned" to `a`.  The `del` statement removes references to objects.  So, doing `del a[:]` is saying "remove all references to objects from within the list assigned to `a`".  The list itself has not changed.  We can see this with the id function, which gives us a number representing an object in memory.  The id of the list before using `del` and after remains the same, indicating the same list object is assigned to `a`.

On the other hand, when we assign a non-empty list to `b` and then assign a new *empty* list to `b`, the id changes.  This is because we have actually moved the `b` reference from the existing `[4, 5, 6]` list to the new `[]` list.

Beyond just the identity of the objects you are dealing with, there are other things to be aware of:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> del a[:]
>>> print a
[]
>>> print b
[]
```

Both `b` and `a` refer to the same list.  Removing the elements from the `a` list without changing the list itself mutates the list in place.  As `b` references the same object, we see the same result there.  If you did `a = []` instead, then `a` will refer to a new empty list while `b` continues to reference the `[1, 2, 3]` list.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> list2 = list1
```

**To get a better understanding, let us see with the help of pictures what happens internally.**

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

This creates a list object and assigns it to `list1`.
[image: Initialization of list1 in memory]

```
>>> list2 = list1
```

The list object which `list1` was referring to is also assigned to `list2`.
[image]

Now, lets look at the methods to empty an list and what actually happens internally.

**METHOD-1: Set to empty list [] :**

```
>>> list1 = []
>>> list2
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

[image: Set list1 to empty list]

This does not delete the elements of the list but deletes the reference to the list. So, `list1` now points to an empty list but all other references will have access to that old `list1`.
This method just creates a new list object and assigns it to `list1`. Any other references will remain.

**METHOD-2: Delete using slice operator[:] :**

```
>>> del list1[:]
>>> list2
[]
```

[image: Delete all elements of list1 using slice operator]

When we use the slice operator to delete all the elements of the list, then all the places where it is referenced, it becomes an empty list. So `list2` also becomes an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, del uses just a little less space in the computer as the person above me implied. The computer still accepts the variable as the same code, except with a different value. However, when you variable is assigned something else, the computer assigns a completely different code ID to it in order to account for the change in memory required.